# How can I display a php page in my overlay using WPML tags?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, wpml

This is part of a plugin I'm creating for training purposes. In one of my pages, I want to overlay another php page. Everything was working fine before I put in my translation tags.

The page displayed in the overlay :
The code is displayed on my page but is cut off at <?php

```
<form class="tracker-rms-form-container" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="tracker-rms-top-part">
        <?php echo '<h2>' . esc_html__( 'Apply Now', 'trackerform' ) . '</h2>'; ?>
        <label class="tracker-rms-label required-field"><i><?php esc_html_e( 'required field', 'trackerform' ) ?></i></br></label>
```

The JS code that displays the overlay :

```
function loadOverlayContent() {
    var overlayContainer = $("<div id='overlayContainer'></div>");
    var closeButton = $("<a href='' id='closeOverlayButton'></a>");

    // Ajoutez la superposition à la page
    $("body").append(overlayContainer);

    // Ajoutez un fond noir semi-transparent
    var backgroundOverlay = $("<div id='backgroundOverlay'></div>");
    $("body").append(backgroundOverlay);

    // Appliquer le style pour afficher le fond noir semi-transparent
    backgroundOverlay.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '0',
        left: '0',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)', // Couleur noire avec une opacité de 65%
        zIndex: '9998', // Un niveau en dessous de l'overlay
    });

    // Charger la page PHP via AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('tracker-rms-form.php', __FILE__)); ?>",
        success: function (data) {
            // Insérer le contenu de la page PHP dans l'overlayContainer
            overlayContainer.html(data);

            // Appliquer le style pour afficher l'overlay devant la page
            overlayContainer.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '50%',
                left: '50%',
                transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
                zIndex: '9999', // Ajustez le z-index en fonction de vos besoins
                backgroundwidth: '100%',
                minWidth: '60%',
                maxHeight: '90%',
                overflow: 'auto',
                scrollbarWidth: 'none',
            });

            // Ajoutez un bouton de fermeture à l'overlay
            overlayContainer.append(closeButton);

            // Ajoutez un événement de clic pour le bouton de fermeture
            closeButton.on("click", function () {
                // Fermez l'overlay lorsqu'on clique sur le bouton de fermeture
                overlayContainer.remove();
                backgroundOverlay.remove();
            });

            // Ajouter un gestionnaire d'événements pour détecter les clics en dehors de l'overlay
            backgroundOverlay.on("click", function (event) {
                if (!$(event.target).closest("#overlayContainer").length) {
                    // Fermer l'overlay si le clic est en dehors de celui-ci
                    overlayContainer.remove();
                    backgroundOverlay.remove();
                }
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            // Gérer les erreurs en cas de problème lors du chargement de la page PHP
            overlayContainer.html("<p>Une erreur s'est produite lors du chargement du contenu.</p>");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Guessing this probably has little to do with AJAX - and if you open that script URL directly in your browser, you are getting the same result?

Comment: Sound like you implemented this as a "stand-alone" script that doesn't include any WP functionality, yet you are still trying to call WP functions - and therefor you probably get a fatal error at this point.

Comment: Yes, if the overlay page works properly when it's open, normally I already use it on another page as well.

Comment: Enable wp debug mode, and see if you get any error messages in the place where the content currently just "stops."

Comment: I've just done it but nothing is displayed about my plugin. I don't know if the fact that it's an overlay means that I can't see the errors.

Comment: You can still go and inspect what response you actually got for that AJAX request, using your browser dev tools (network panel.)

Comment: I'm not very good with development tools but I've got a tracker-rms-form.php request in networks which is the element supposed to be displayed in the overlay that cuts off just before the <?php

Comment: "Cuts off" _is_ a pretty sure sign that you have a fatal error in your script at that point, that it can't recover from. If you are not getting any errors, then you probably have not made the correct settings in that regard yet.

Comment: Okay, and how do I do that? Because I don't see the problem.

Comment: Have you not enabled debug mode yet? https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/debug/debug-wordpress/

Comment: Yes, the general debug mode is activated >[define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);] should I activate the script mode?

Comment: Don't think script mode would help much here, your issue does not appear to be primarily related to the client-side scripting. Maybe something else in your setup (a plugin perhaps) has deactivated `display_errors` again. What happens when you enable WP_DEBUG_LOG as well, and then check the log file?

Comment: I've just done it and nothing comes up when I search for the name of my files.

Comment: Okay, just to be clear, I am asking again: When you open the result of `<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('tracker-rms-form.php', __FILE__)); ?>` directly in a new browser tab, then everything looks as it should?

Comment: Yes, perfectly.

Comment: Can't see that making much sense, because between that request and your AJAX, there should not be much of a significant difference. The AJAX request will send an additional header letting the server know this was an AJAX request - but if you are not explicitly checking for that anywhere and do something different based on it, then I suppose it could only be WPML itself, that somehow recognizes this scenario, and somehow handles it differently. But then again in _that_ case, I would expect it to handle this "gracefully", and not with a hard error that ends all script execution at this point.

Comment: Not sure if it could perhaps be related to something like this, https://wpml.org/errata/unable-to-get-site-language-on-the-front-end-ajax-calls-when-user-is-not-logged-in/ (although I can't see that making much sense either - if the cookie was missing _and_ there was no language specifier in the URL, then I don't see why the direct call of that URL should behave different.)

Comment: Yes, I don't understand it either, and the fact that there's no error message really bothers me. 
In any case, thank you very much for your investment